# How to filter deceptive 'bait & switch' price listings on Ebay when sorted by price?

Tags: ebay

Example: When searching for "micro hdmi hdmi", I obtain the following list of items.

[image]

Looking good, at a cheap price.

[image]
[image]
However, upon actually selecting the image, the prices changes to a higher price, therefore wasting my time clicking on the deceptive seller's item listing. The seller deceptively lists an irrelevant item (in this case the RJ45 connector) at the 0.99 price, therefore putting his item ahead of competitors despite the fact that his price is far higher.
[image]

This technique apparently violates the official [Ebay policies](http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-circumventing.html), as seen here (emphasis mine):

> Not Allowed:
>
> Selling different brands of an item, such as jeans, in a single listing
>
> Offering a choice between **two entirely different items, such as a watch or pair of shoes**
>
> Selling items that aren't in similar condition, such as a new and a refurbished laptop, in the same listing

Is there a way to outright remove these "select X from a list" listings, or another technique, in order to avoid the deceptive sellers? This has become extremely common, literally every one of the 0.99 pound sellers are deceptively advertising their prices.

Comment: I think the only way to avoid those is to view auction-style listings only.  I don't think you can avoid them if you want to look at Buy It Now listings.

Comment: @pnuts Can you show a screenshot of you selecting an actual item and the price remaining the same? It has been happening for me for multiple items, this was the latest one I looked for.

Comment: I agree as I find a lot of these as well. Comes up first due to low price sort, but when you pick any ITEM, there is no item at that price. Bait & Switch - Example:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-6-6s-64GB-GSM-Unlocked-4-7-3D-Touch-iOS-Smartphone-US-Version/182252820469?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D38636%26meid%3Da275ddb3a71745ef884cbd69166fac7f%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D14%26sd%3D172319924453

Answer (score 9):

I thought I'd post my hacky solution for anyone else stumbling across this in the future.

This works as of May 15, 2017. eBay may change its DOM structure in the meantime. In that case, this will have to be adapted.

1. Open up the developer console (<kbd>F12</kbd> or right click > Inspect)
2. Click the "Console" tab
3. Copy+Paste the following and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   $("#ListViewInner > li").each((idx, li) => {
       if(li.innerHTML.indexOf("prRange") > 0)
         li.remove();
     });
   ```

This just deletes every node that contains the "prRange" class. In principle, something similar to this should work even if eBay changes the structure of their page. You just need to find the resulting container (ListViewInner) and some token that's present in the price range results and is not present in the regular results (prRange)

Answer (score 8):

This solution is based on [DaveInCaz and larsolafsimonsen's fantastic answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106111/177684) which I have used many times but no longer seems to work for me (possibly eBay changed the DOM as a mentioned susceptibility).

1. Open up the developer console (<kbd>F12</kbd> or right click > Inspect)
2. Click the **Console** tab
3. Copy + Paste the following and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

`$('.DEFAULT').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();`

This is based on the eBay search results as at `15/05/2018`. Listings with a price range have a span element between the two prices $xx to $xx with the class DEFAULT. This code looks up the tree to delete the node this came from. This will likely fail in the future when eBay changes structure again.

Comment: As of 2018-09-08 the command is $('.prRange').parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();

Answer (score 5):

It's worth mentioning that, as this type of listing format is against eBay policy, it can be (and usually should be) reported.  When reporting the listing, it can be hard to find the correct issue to report.  This problem is confusingly listed under:
*Listing Practices
Avoiding Ebay Fees
Offering Choices*
This seems like an odd organization, but the description given there makes it clear that this is the correct choice to report the issue: 
"The listing has different brands of an item, **a choice between two entirely different items,** or items that aren't in similar condition."

Answer (score 5):

I implemented and updated [Brendan Wilding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/117127/159524)'s answer as a [greasemonkey/tampermonkey script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/370761-ebay-remove-listings-with-multiple-prices)

Answer (score 2):

I had some success by filtering out the junk items the guy is using to make the price seem lower. In your case, try adding a "-RJ45" after your search query and enable "search description". This would exclude all listings that have the RJ45 as any part of their listing

I had this issue with iPhone 6es with people selling a 4s as another option, making their listing for a "6s" look like a really good deal when it isn't.

Really annoying. Hope eBay finds a way to deal with this.